# Handling Event Listeners in a Object Orientated Style

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm trying to apply what I learned in a tutorial. I'm learning OOP at the moment and wondering how to handle event listeners in a object orientated way. I have learned the functional sort of way were you store a DOM query selector in a global constant so its available everywhere then I can add a event listeners at the bottom of my code. However how would I go about doing this through the OOP way as I assume that there shouldn't be any global variables. Would I query select in an constructor method or a static class ? How do you handle event listeners in your projects when coding in a object orientated way ?

Comment: You can simply use a class property instead of a global variable. There's nothing about event listeners that changes this.

Comment: can you share what you tried?